# How would I map a network drive on a system that's behind a router?

Tags: networking, routing

My end objective is to synchronize a directory structure on machine A (Win7) to what's on machine B (Win 8.1).  There are multiple programs out there that will do a good job of this when they can see the drives but A and B are in different cities, both behind consumer-level routers.  Is there any good system for doing this?

Programs like Teamviewer will let you copy files but I haven't seen any that are good at synchronizing.

Comment: +1 for question. I had this issue, end up having dedicated static IPs for machines. Which might not be doable in your case. Did you consider running VPN connection?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your end result is to get the content the same on 2 machines at different locations, the best option is to use cloud-based synchronisation, such as Google drive, One Drive, Dropbox, etc.

The downside of this is that you are limited to a filesize, but this can still be enough. Google Drive offers 15GB nowadays.

The upside is that setting up the synchronisation is really easy, and since the data is in the cloud, it is accessible everywhere. Adding a third and fourth pc to synch is also an option now.

If using cloud storage is not your option (because the data is just too much, or you don't want it to be in the cloud) then you'll have to go for a connection between the 2 pc's. VPN is best practice to use, but alternatively, remote desktop with the check to bring network shares to the remote computer can be used to get access to the local files from the remote computer.

The synchronization part after that can be tricky though, and probably will require VPN or manual actions each time you want to synchronize.

Comment: The data volume is considerable although the turnover is only a few percent per day.  I don't think 15gb would do it but there are options that have more.  I'll look into this approach.

Answer (score 1):

BitTorrent Sync (https://www.getsync.com) is an option... (although looks like it has got a commercial "pro" version now).

Install it on the PC/device that you have data on, and claim "this is my first sync device", set up the folder you want to copy across, click on "share" and email out (or copy or whatever) the specially crafted link to the destination PC.

On the destination PC, you can just use that link (as it seems to lead to a web page to download sync client), and once both PCs paired to each other, it will start moving files between your PC

In a way BT Sync works the same principle with BitTorrent which is peer to peer traffic, so there are no clouds in between, just direct connection. If BitTorrent traffic aren't blocked by your router, then BT Sync will work.

Comment: Strange that a program that doesn't seem that it needs server support has a per year licensing system.

Comment: Completely agreed with you there. The free version works fine tho. The pro just have some additional features that you may / may not care.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the only way to do this is to set up a Virtual Private Network ([VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)) connection between the two computers.  VPN provides a conduit through which computers and/or networks behave as though they are connected on the same 'physical' network/subnet.  You could then use whatever synch application you prefer across the VPN connection.

A quick Google search turned up [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) as a free option for noncommercial use.  I've never used it; presumably you'd have to install on both systems, properly configure one computer as 'listener' and one as 'connector', and then define and open the appropriate IP addresses and ports.  I'm sure there are other applications out there, both free and commercial.

The level of security of such an arrangement will only be as good as the software available.